# Main menu in a FoxPro 9 app

Tags: visual-foxpro

If you use the Visual FoxPro 9 **Application Framework** to create a desktop standalone application and add a database and form, the exported exe shows a Quick Start on load which shows the form to select.

If one wants to show up his own MAIN MENU form on the exe load, what's the way to do it? Using **Set Main** on the Menu Form does not work.

[Here is a visual representation of the idea.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJdcP.png)

Comment: I THOUGHT you already had the code and a running baseline project that you just wanted to add a newer form to be the primary.  Is that correct?  OR... when you referred to VFP9 Application Framework, you were just referring to the VFP 9 development environment TO BUILD applications.  If you are STARTING FROM SCRATCH (brand new project), let me know.

Comment: yes its a new application, and I am working on it. Application Framework offered some readymade features but I think I'll manage without it.

Comment: revised with very basic baseline as an entry point for you, THEN, you can add in all the other "ready made feature" forms you want to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its simplest steps then, aside from the "Wizards" you can use to build forms and bind to data environments, tables, grids, etc maybe this will help.

Create an empty project.

CREATE PROJECT MyApp

Go to the documents tab and add a new form.  Put a few buttons as you've described on it.  One of the buttons, allow to close the form, such as "Exit".  Double click this exit button and put in the code

```
CLEAR EVENTS
THISFORM.RELEASE()
```

Since there are no "data entry" elements on this form, we need something to make it keep focus.  Buttons alone don't just "do" that.  Go to the properties sheet of the form and go down to "Window Type" and set it to "Modal" - meaning, keep this form up until its intentionally closed.  (This also keeps as a baseline for you calling any OTHER forms from this one for your application.)  Save the form, such as "MyMainForm".

Click on the "Code" tab of the project and do a new "Program".  In its simplest context, put in

```
DO FORM MyMainForm
READ EVENTS
```

Save the program, such as MyStartupProgram.  Once saved in the project, right-click on this program and select "Set Main" for this to be considered the single entry point to your entire application.  Save, build the project and run it.  You should be good to go.

Comment: seems you misunderstood my question, but I actually wanted a menu UI [as in this image](http://i.imgur.com/NAstB.png) , not a menu bar on top

Comment: The application framework has got no `DO`s and `READ EVENTS`. I'll have to do without it, using a blank application.